# How to configure http proxy (Squid?) to transform http/1.1 requests to 1.0

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I need to setup Squid (or any other proxy) on my local linux VM so that it proxies all incoming HTTP traffic on the loopback interface while transforming the HTTP version to 1.0.

In other words I need to be able to send HTTP/1.1 requests from the host to the VM, where the Squid intercepts it at the interface and changes HTTP version to 1.0. I do not care about the response version.

Is this even possible?